# the usage of て in それて何

Tags: particle-って

I saw that それて何 has the same meaning as それが何 but I'm not sure how. What is the usage of て in this sentence?

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you saw was それって.

Comment: Do you have more context? Is what you see a complete sentence on its own?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure the one you saw is それって何。 って is a colloquial version of the particle は or the quoting particle と. So, それって何 is the vernacular version of それは何。

Other examples where って replaces と or は in speech:

> あのラーメン屋**は**めっちゃ美味しかったね
> あのラーメン屋**って**めっちゃ美味しかったね

> 彼が「だめ」**と**答えた
> 彼が「だめ」**って**答えた